# Why do I get permission denied for a directory with acl set for the owner of the directory (after removing all standard posix permissions)?

Tags: permissions, acl

I'm attempting to execute the `ls` command on a directory which has acl permissions for the owner and group of the directory (with no standard posix permissions set). This results in a Permission Denied even though `getfacl` says the user should be able to do so.

Here's what I'm doing:

1. Create a directory and a file inside it.

`mkdir /tmp/mydir && touch /tmp/mydir/myfile`

2. Check if I can execute `ls` on this directory.

```
jgazula@gazula:/tmp$ ls -al /tmp/mydir/
total 896
drwxrwxr-x  2 jgazula jgazula   4096 Nov  1 11:57 .
drwxrwxrwt 25 root    root    909312 Nov  1 11:57 ..
-rw-rw-r--  1 jgazula jgazula      0 Nov  1 11:57 myfile
```

3. Now, let's remove all the standard posix permissions on this directory.

`chmod 000 /tmp/mydir`

4. Verify the permissions.

```
jgazula@gazula:/tmp$ ls -al /tmp | grep mydir
d---------  2 jgazula jgazula   4096 Nov  1 11:57 mydir
```

5. We shouldn't be able to `ls` now.

```
jgazula@gazula:/tmp$ ls -al /tmp/mydir/
ls: cannot open directory '/tmp/mydir/': Permission denied
```

6. Set the acl permissions for the `jgazula` user and group.

`sudo setfacl --mask -Rm u:jgazula:rwx,g:jgazula:rwx /tmp/mydir/`

7. Verify the acl permissions.

```
jgazula@gazula:/tmp$ getfacl -ep /tmp/mydir/
# file: /tmp/mydir/
# owner: jgazula
# group: jgazula
user::---
user:jgazula:rwx        #effective:rwx
group::---          #effective:---
group:jgazula:rwx       #effective:rwx
mask::rwx
other::---
```

8. Since the acl permissions (including the effective permissions) look good, I should be able to execute `ls` on the directory?

```
jgazula@gazula:/tmp$ ls -al /tmp/mydir/
ls: cannot open directory '/tmp/mydir/': Permission denied
```

But I can't and I don't understand why.

9. Interestingly enough, when I check the standard posix permissions, the group permission bits have been set? Not sure I understand why only group permissions have been updated.

```
jgazula@gazula:/tmp$ ls -al /tmp | grep mydir
d---rwx---+  2 jgazula jgazula   4096 Nov  1 12:13 mydir
```

10. Let's set the acl permissions for the owner and group (i.e, omit the owner/group from the command).

`sudo setfacl --mask -Rm u::rwx,g::rwx /tmp/mydir/`

11. Verify the acl permissions again.

```
jgazula@gazula:/tmp$ getfacl -ep /tmp/mydir/
# file: /tmp/mydir/
# owner: jgazula
# group: jgazula
user::rwx
user:jgazula:rwx        #effective:rwx
group::rwx          #effective:rwx
group:jgazula:rwx       #effective:rwx
mask::rwx
other::---
```

12. Check if I can execute `ls` now.

```
jgazula@gazula:/tmp$ ls -al /tmp/mydir/
total 896
drwxrwx---+  2 jgazula jgazula   4096 Nov  1 11:57 .
drwxrwxrwt  25 root    root    909312 Nov  1 11:57 ..
-rwxrwxr--+  1 jgazula jgazula      0 Nov  1 11:57 myfile
```

Why does step #6 not work by itself? I'm setting the acl permissions explicitly for a user and group. Why do I need to execute step #11?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run `sudo setfacl --mask -Rm u:jgazula:rwx,g:jgazula:rwx /tmp/mydir/`, you are creating an `ACL_USER` entry for user `jgazula`. But the `ACL_USER_OBJ` for the owner of the file is still `---`. (You can see this in the `getfacl` output in step 7.)

According to `man ACL`, the access check algorithm goes:

> ```
> 1.   If the effective user ID of the process matches the user ID of the file object owner, then
>            if the ACL_USER_OBJ entry contains the requested permissions, access is granted,
>            else access is denied.
>
> 2.   else if the effective user ID of the process matches the qualifier of any entry of type ACL_USER, then
>            if the matching ACL_USER entry and the ACL_MASK entry contain the requested permissions, access is granted,
>            else access is denied.
> ```

So the `ACL_USER` entry is never even checked.

There is essentially the same question on serverfault: [ACL: giving - - - permissions for the owner of the file](https://serverfault.com/q/808108/410129). (But it looks like the answer there got `ACL_USER` vs `ACL_USER_OBJ` reversed.)